# Auto-populate a field based on information in two different fields

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, merge, attribute-joins, relates

I am attempting to auto-populate a field using matching information in two different fields in ArcGIS Pro.

The field that I am trying to populate is "Unique_ID." Table #1 includes three fields, "Unique_ID", "Site_Number", and "Facility". Table #2 includes "Site_Number" and "Facility" but is blank for "Unique_ID". In both tables, both "Site_Number" and "Facility" have several rows with the same values. In other words, each "Site_Number" has multiple records with different "Facility" values, and vice versa. I would like to populate the "Unique_ID" field in Table #2 based on matching records for both "Site_Number" and "Facility" in Table #1.

Table #1:

| Unique_ID | Site_Number | Facility |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100456 | 2786 | 33 |
| 100456 | 2786 | 33 |
| 100456 | 2786 | 33 |
| 100892 | 2786 | 45 |
| 100892 | 2786 | 45 |
| 108963 | 3005 | 33 |
| 108963 | 3005 | 33 |
| 104750 | 3005 | 72 |
| 104750 | 3005 | 72 |
| 105261 | 3005 | 45 |
| 105261 | 3005 | 45 |

Table #2:

| Unique_ID | Site_Number | Facility |
| --- | --- | --- |
| tbd | 2786 | 33 |
| tbd | 2786 | 33 |
| tbd | 2786 | 33 |
| tbd | 2786 | 45 |
| tbd | 2786 | 45 |
| tbd | 3005 | 33 |
| tbd | 3005 | 33 |
| tbd | 3005 | 72 |
| tbd | 3005 | 72 |
| tbd | 3005 | 45 |

Expected Output:

| Unique_ID | Site_Number | Facility |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100456 | 2786 | 33 |
| 100456 | 2786 | 33 |
| 100456 | 2786 | 33 |
| 100892 | 2786 | 45 |
| 100892 | 2786 | 45 |
| 108963 | 3005 | 33 |
| 108963 | 3005 | 33 |
| 104750 | 3005 | 72 |
| 104750 | 3005 | 72 |
| 105261 | 3005 | 45 |

Comment: Can you include a mock table and expected output in your question? This sounds like a Join using Make Query Table could solve your problem. https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/make-query-table.htm

Comment: Just added mock tables and expected output

Comment: You should get rid of the duplicates if you can because that will cause a one-to-many join. Join based on multiple attributes is possible using the Make Query Table tool, see the first comment. Another option is to create a new column and use calculate field to concatenate the fields you want to join by into a single column, acting as a composite key. Do that for for both tables then do a regular Add Join.